# How to get integer values from nsstring Evalution in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

I have NSString like this `@"0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2012-03-08,2012-03-17"`. I want values separated by comma. I want values before comma and neglect comma.

I am new in iPhone, I know how to do in Java but not getting how to do in Objective-C.

Comment: That list contains both dates and integers, what do you want the dates formatted as?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
NSString *string = @"0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2012-03-08,2012-03-17";

NSArray *componentArray = [string componentSeperatedByString:@","];
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`componentsSeparatedByString:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-componentsSeparatedByString_) method of `NSString`.

```
NSString *str = @"0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2012-03-08,2012-03-17";
NSArray *components = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

for (NSString *comp in components)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", comp);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for (NSString *s in [yourstring componentsSeparatedByString:@","])
{
    int thisval = [s intValue];
}
```